# findOneAndUpdate mongoose in node.js failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I got an error of Account.findOneAndUpdate is not a function using POSTMAN. Any clue what's wrong with my model below?

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

var Account = new Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    createAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    status: {type: String, default: 'Active'}
});

Account.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model('accounts', Account);

module.exports.updateStatus = function(username,callback){
    var update = {status:'Completed'};
    Account.findOneAndUpdate({username:username},update).exec(callback);
}
```

I want to update the **status** to **completed**

When I do console.log(username) I'm able to see I can get the value.

Answer (score 2):

`findOneAndUpdate` is a method on the model, not the schema.

```
var AccountSchema = new Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    createAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    status: {type: String, default: 'Active'}
});

AccountSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

var Account = mongoose.model('accounts', AccountSchema);
module.exports = Account;

module.exports.updateStatus = function(username,callback){
    var update = {status:'Completed'};
    Account.findOneAndUpdate({username:username},update).exec(callback);
}
```

But you probably want to clean up your exports as you're using the model as your `exports` object but then adding `updateStatus` to that.

Comment: You striped this line `module.exports = mongoose.model('accounts', Account);` will it effect other part of my app?

Comment: It's functionally still there; I just split it into two statements so that the `Account` model could be used by `updateStatus`.

Comment: I saw somewhere it is one line. Like `var Account = module.exports = mongoose.model('account',AccountSchema);`

Comment: That way works fine as well. Same result either way.